# How to determine transparency level of a pixel in Fireworks

Tags: adobe-fireworks, transparency

I am a moderate user of Photoshop and have never really used Fireworks. I have been given a Fireworks document which I need to modify.

The document has just one layer, the background layer. On it are some icons and some of them have a semi-transparent border which I am needing to recolor.

If I use the eyedropper tool on a border pixel, I get the semi-transparent color value which changes based on what color I have the canvas set to.

Is there any way I can see what the original border color is/was, and what the transparency level is set to?

Comment: What type of objects are the icons (vector/bitmap/symbol/autoshape)?

Answer (score 1):

To get a color and transparency values from a bitmap pixel, copy the color to another shape's fill color. From there you will be able to read it's values.

For example create a rectangle shape, and pick a color from the bitmap by opening the color pick dialog:

[image]

Then open the color dialog again to view the values:

[image]

**Note:** I'm using Fireworks CS6 version. Earlier versions may be different or lack this feature.

Comment: I have CS5, and don't see anything called Color Dialog or any way to call something like that up. All I see at the bottom of the screen is Eyedropper Tool under Properties. Since the image is flattened, there's no objects to select on the image.

Comment: Just create any new shape, like I created a rectangle in the above example, and select it. The color dialog pops up when you click the little color box on the right from the bucket icon on the `Properties` panel. Your cursor will automatically become eyedropper when it pops up.

Comment: Okay, I did that. CS5 must be different. I get the popup, but aside from the color boxes, there's nothing underneath to indicate transparency. I don't have enough points to post a screenshot. Above the color boxes is a bar with a rectangle dynamically showing the color under the eyedropper tool. Next to that is a field showing the hexcode equivalent of the color. Next to that is a copy icon. Next to that is a transparency icon, which if I click it, changes the rectangle color to transparent. Next to that is a color wheel like what you have on your screen in the lower right of the popup.

Comment: I'm afraid that you'll have to do it manually with a certain degree of proximity then. Select the pixel using marquee tool, copy and paste it as a new bitmap, size it up for a better visual comparison. Create a new shape with the fill color from the bitmap, and place it next to it. Then you can play with transparency until they're visually the same. Or, consider upgrading to CS6 of course.